# Azure Kubernetes - Auto-scaling & Nodeselector, Taint and Tolerance?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster with the below configuration

1. Windows Node Pools - 1
2. Nodes - 2
3. Node Labels - 2 : app1, app2
4. Pods - 4 : two pods for each app, node is selected based on the nodeselector
5. Pod uses Taint & Tolerance
6. Node auto-scaling is enabled

Now, lets says if a new node is created to support the additional load of app1. would that new node labelled automatically and taint is applied so that app1 can be deployed on that node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a nodepool, you can specify labels and taints (--nodetaints) that would be applied automatically.  Once the nodepool is created, I don't think you can currently go back and add that auto-label or auto-tainting ability.